# Connecting to car CANbus

Tags: can-bus

I have a CANLogger 2000 and the correct supplier supplied ODB-II CANBus to 9 pin D-type cable. (http://www.csselectronics.com/screen/product/can-bus-logger-canlogger2000/language/en)

The CANLogger has 8GB internal memory, I have connected the device to my car (AUDI A5 2012) and the module lights up as it should with the green LED illuminated.

I originally had a problem with the device trying to auto detect the bitrate and failing, so I edited the CONFIG.INI and set the bit rate manually to 500000 which according to AUDI is the correct bit rate for the car.

However I do not see any activity logged and I'm not sure if this is why the module was unable to detect the bit rate.

I don't know if its as simple as connecting the module to the car and it will start logging or if data is available on the connector?

Does anyone have experience with sniffing the CANbus on an AUDI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access the CAN bus for any useable data from the OBD port in late VAG vehicles. The port only responds to PIDs and manufacturer specific data as it is connected to a communication gateway.

For the purposes of logging, sniffing, reverse engineering etc you need to access the relevant CAN bus channel as there could be up to 6 CAN bus channels in a VAG vehicle, a good one to use is the CAN bus connected to the instrument cluster. Most info is available on one or more of the buses connect to it and its relatively easy to physically access. Failing that you can connect at the BCM or connect directly to the gateway.

It entirely depends on what data you need, why you need it and what you're going to do with it. If you are just sniffing/monitoring the instrument cluster usually has most of the info you want as it displays a lot of engine and speed data, doors open/close, audio etc.

If you want to send messages to the vehicle such as command door locks or windows you will need to find the relevant PIDs/VAG codes to send through the OBD port. As there are so many people hacking vehicles now you could probably find them online but you could use a diagnostics machine and look at what messages are sent for each command and replicate that yourself.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any links of information that could aid me?